# How to retrieve the GPS location from a geotagged image on BlackBerry?

Tags: image, blackberry, geolocation

This is what I have tried so far:

1. Reading the metadata info of an EncodedImage by using the [getMetaData()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/EncodedImage.html#getMetaData%28%29) method. However [MetaDataControl](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/javax/microedition/media/control/MetaDataControl.html) does not contains keys for the information that I need.
2. Using the [GeotaggedPhotoPicker](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/lbs/picker/GeotaggedPhotoPicker.html) class. The problem here is that I don't need users to browse and select a photo, I already know the path to the photo that I need. I could use this if the picker would give me access to the actual image as well, not just to the geotag info.

Does anyone have any other suggestions of how to access the gps information from a geotagged image?

Comment: Is there any relevant key available in `getKeys()`?, http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/javax/microedition/media/control/MetaDataControl.html#getKeys%28%29.

Comment: No, nothing related to gps location.